# Webcomponent doesn't load in IE11 with Polymer

Tags: polymer, internet-explorer-11

I've build an webcomponent with Polymer, and it works on all browsers except for IE11.
I've tried everything but can't figure out why it doesn't work.

Attached is the code, could you help me figure out why?
It remains at the loading.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, initial scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
<title>wc test</title>
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
<script src="/node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
<script>if(!window.customElements){document.write("<!--")}</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js"></script>
<!-- do not remove -->
<script src="/node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="/src/klantenvertellen-app/klantenvertellen-app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<klantenvertellen-app>Loading...</klantenvertellen-app>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which polymer version are you using? And if you are using Polymer 3 are you using lit-element/lit-html?

Comment: Any errors logged on console?